# Can a mint's supply or decimals ever change?

Tags: account, token, instructions, mint

I am building a data ingestion pipeline for solana blockchain data, and trying to determine whether it is safe for my processing pipeline to classify a given mint as an NFT based on whether the supply is 1, and the number of decimals is 0.  I understand that fields such as the "mint authority" can be later modified after the initial mint account is created.  Is the same true for supply and decimals?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the NFT Standard on Solana then you also have to create a metadata account and a master edition account along with the mint account. The master edition is going to have the mint authority and it makes sure no one can change the supply. So to answer your question to classify a mint as a NFT you have to make sure it has mint account with supply 1 and decimal of 0 and make sure metadata and master-edition account exists for that mint.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.  My question was more about whether or not fields such as total supply and decimals can ever be changed.  I'm trying to understand what is / isn't mutable.

Comment: No they cant be changed by a user or holder directly even the creator cant change these things. The mint authority is given to the master edition PDA so it's the token metadata contract that defines the rules around this

Answer (score 0):

If a token has a supply of 1 and a non-null mint authority, there's always the possibility that the mint authority creates another token.  Supply is changed anytime a token is minted.

Decimals, however, can never be changed.